# How much should I water sunchokes to get a patch going?

Tags: watering, sunchoke

I'm trying to start a sunchoke patch (for perpetual farming), and was wondering how much I should be watering them to get them to sprout quicker similar to an artificial spring?

Comment: It will depend on your climate and location. Here in the UK sunchokes (aka Jerusalem Artichokes) don't need at watering at all as there's plenty of rain.

Comment: How often should they get watered in any way/shape/form?

Comment: @Organic what percentage of humidity is optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On planting, [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Grow-Sunchokes-or-Jerusalem-Artichokes) advises:

> After you have planted the rhizomes in the soil, you will want to water thoroughly until some drains through the bottom of the container. Sunchokes, like sunflowers, appreciate water, although many people have had success growing in dry climates. 2"-3" a week should be fine.

Therefater, for watering [Harvest To Table](http://www.harvesttotable.com/2009/03/how_to_grow_sunchoke/) advises:

> Sunchokes grow best with an even, regular supply of water but can survive long periods of drought once established.

This is typical of Helianthus (sunflowers). [Wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_artichoke) mentions "Jerusalem artichokes are easy to cultivate, which tempts gardeners to simply leave them completely alone to grow."

[RHS](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/vegetables/jerusalem-artichoke) has growing advice which includes "Keep well watered in dry weather".
If the plants are too healthy they can become a nuisance, why a degree of neglect has been chosen deliberately by [Colleen Vanderlinden](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-grow-organic-jerusalem-artichokes-2539639):

> Less coddling (less amending of soil, less watering, no fertilizing) seems to help keep them under control as well -- they have not been nearly as invasive in my garden using these methods.

Unless excessive, watering is likely to have little impact on the speed of sprouting, that may depend more on temperature.